# How to send email after moving the file from one folder to another

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library

I have one document library, in which I am sending an email with file URL to user after uploaded the file (I'm using event receiver for sending emails).

But in case, **If file is moved then user get 404 file not found error**. So how can I resolve this issue? Is there any way to send another email after file moved?

Any solution is  acceptable like OOTB or code or workflow or anything else. Thank you.

Comment: How do you move files?

Comment: @love Through browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using event receiver, add new event receiver - ItemFileMoved to send mail on moving file.

Comment: Thanks monica but [This method is misnamed. It does not handle a file movement across document libraries, regardless of whether the movement is done programmatically or through the SharePoint user interface.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemfilemoved.aspx)

Comment: I tried using ItemFileMoved event receiver but it doesnt hit as mentioned by msdn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "alert me" without code. Check this out
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-alert-to-get-notified-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-in-SharePoint-e5a79e7b-a146-46da-a9ef-d65409ba8918